# How to execute Karate-gatling simulation from Java program instead of gradle gatlingRun

Tags: karate

I have implemented karate-gatling-demo and it works fine with Gradle gradle gatlingRun
Is there a way to start gatling from Java code?
I have tried ProcessBuilder with same args we pass in gradle task but it doesn't pick catsimulation Scala  class file
e.g

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe",io.gatling.app.Gatling -s mock.catsimulation -rf ${buildDir}/reports/gatling);
pb.start();
```

Any other way to achieve gatling execution from Java ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your classpath is incomplete. In the maven world you can do this:

```
mvn test-compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=my.main.Class -Dexec.args='-some -args' -Dexec.classpathScope=test
```